# Should We Restrain Book-Reference/Rock-Identification Questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, rock-identification-guide

I suspect people can **farm** reputation points off of book reference requests, I would like to propose a system where one asks for a book reference they would not gain any reputation when upvoted on the specific question asked. I am not sure how this system would be implemented, Moderators or Staff could manually do it. The same could apply for Rock-Identification and etc. Please let me know through Answer/Comment about the plausibility of this proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be implemented as follows:

We could have a policy in which people *should* mark reference requests as community wiki.  For community wiki questions, no reputation is earned.  If a reference request is not marked as community wiki, then anyone could flag the question for moderator assistance and ask a moderator to turn the question into community wiki.

Is this what we want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I would want, and I think other people probably want this.

Comment: I agree with this proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Rock identification requests are off topic (as far as I know reference requests are valid).

If users start farming points with repetitive softball questions, I would think it would be addressed (perhaps by the voting of users becoming wise to it, as has occurred a bit in the past with answerers who tended to make up/fluff answers without knowing the topic well, such that their answers wound up fraught with errors... or perhaps by new rules).

But as of current, I don't know that I've seen users regularly attempting to do this, so don't think this needs any proposal/change as of now?